# Creating an undefined amount of Jlabels in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm making a program in Java using Java swing. I'm including a search function and the results of this search are held in an ArrayList string. I need to display these results, but as its a search it not possible to know to amount of items which are held in the array. So how can I create and add an unknown number of Jlabels?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the same way you store the strings you are looking for?

Comment: The problem is when I already have the results of the search. So now I'm trying to display what has been returned by the search in the jframe

Comment: I suggest using a `JList`

Comment: I strongly second @Jonah's suggestion that you use JList. Not only would it simplify things, but it would also allow your program to use less resources and thus likely be a little more responsive. If you show us pertinent code, preferably your [mcve] (please read the link), we could likely show you helpful code for this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thanks for your answer, that's what I needed, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, show your images within a JList for ease and also for selectability.

for example:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImageList extends JPanel {
    private static final String BASE_PATH = "http://file.kelleybluebookimages.com/"
            + "kbb/images/content/editorial/";
    private static final String[] PATHS = {
        "2015-acura-tlx-guide-180.jpg",
        "13A420TFSI_01_hrgb-180.jpg",
        "CT_071713_BMW320i_0439-180.jpg",
        "2013-Cadillac-ATS-137-180.jpg",
        "EJ2V1342-180.jpg",
        "2014LexusIS005-180.jpg",
        "2014-volvo-s60-180.jpg",
        "2015-jeep-renegade-profile-180.jpg"
    };
    private DefaultListModel<Icon> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private JList<Icon> imageJList = new JList<>(listModel);

    public ImageList() throws IOException {
        for (String path : PATHS) {
            String imgPath = BASE_PATH + path;
            URL url = new URL(imgPath);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
            listModel.addElement(new ImageIcon(img));
        }

        imageJList.setVisibleRowCount(4);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imageJList);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        add(scrollPane);
    }    

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ImageList");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try {
            frame.getContentPane().add(new ImageList());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can figure out this likewise,

```
// you already have this searched result's arraylist
ArralyList<String> allsearchresult = new ArrayList<String>();

JLabel ll = null;
for(String label : allsearchresult ){
   ll = new JLabel(label);
   frame.add(ll); // it's my idea, it can be change according you req.
   // set other necessary requirements...
}
```

Comment: The default LayoutManager of a JFrame is BorderLaqyout. Adding multiple items to the frame will end up with only one item showing. Better to add a JPanel to the frame and then use a JList in the panel as @Jonah suggested.